# Linear system of conics passing through $3$ points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, divisors-algebraic-geometry, quasicoherent-sheaves, line-bundles

I would like to understand why the set of classes of divisors corresponding to the conics of $\mathbb P^2$ passing through $3$ non-colinear points is a linear system of dimension $2$.

Thank you very much.

Edit :

Well, there are $6$ degree $2$ monomials of $k[x_0,x_1,x_2]$. We can identify all the conics with $\mathbb P^5$. Then, when one fixes a point contained in the conic, it implies that the conic belongs to a hyperplane of $\mathbb P^5$. By the same way, fixing $1\le k\le 5$ points of the conic determines a projective subspace of $\mathbb P^5$ of dimension $5-k$. So in our case, the projective subspace which parametrizes all possible conics is of dimension $2$. What is still unclear for me is how to translate it properly into the language of linear system of divisors.

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you know what sort of condition "passing through a point" enforces on the equations for the conics?

Comment: @KReiser thank you for your answer. I edit my question.

Comment: What is your definition of a linear system? Can you identify any parts of this definition with the particular situation?

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you. After a few hours reviewing all the definitions, I get that the complete linear system of conics is isomorphic to $\mathbb P(H^0(\mathbb P^2,\mathcal O(2)))$. The point that I still miss (and maybe the most important) is the identification $|D|\leftrightarrow\mathbb P(H^0(\mathbb P^2,\mathcal O(D)))$. The definition I know of $H^0(\mathbb P^2,\mathcal O(D))$ is $\{0\}\cup\{f\in k(\mathbb P^2),(f)+D\ge0\}$.